# Estoy exportando los datos de un datagridview a un excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

necesito exportar los datos que le voy introduciendo en el datagrid a un excel pero me da el siguiente error **Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800AC472**

El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Boletin7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btguardarexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
            objExcel.Visible = true; //Podríamos trabajar sin que se vea…
            Excel.Workbook objLibro = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
            Excel.Worksheet objHoja =
           (Excel.Worksheet)objLibro.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //hoja 1

            for (int i=1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count+1; i++)
            {
                objHoja.Cells[i,1] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    objHoja.Cells[i+2, j+1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialoge.FileName = "output";
            saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";

            if(saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                objLibro.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }



        }

        private void btSalirexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult salir = MessageBox.Show("Seguro?", "Salir", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (salir == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien podría ayudarme con este caso estaría muy agradecido, Muchas gracias de antemano.
El fallo esta aqui `objHoja.Cells[i,1] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;`

Comment: dicen que Interop es muy antiguo y que probablemente debas usar OpenXML, ahí va un link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Comment: Prueba agregando el atributo Value:   objHoja.Cells[i,1].Value = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;